# KeyError: "['id' 'x_center' 'y_center'] not in index"

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file that contains four columns and many rows so I covert these columns and make one row and many columns after that i want to save to new file with specific id i mean hear i have 4 unique id so for every id it will save to new file but unfortunately i found this error

> KeyError: "['id' 'x_center' 'y_center'] not in index"

this my code

```
import pandas as pd 
df= pd.read_csv('./1_1.csv')
df=df.sort_values(by = 'id')
s = df['id'].unique()
for i in s:     
    df=df[["id" ,"x_center" , "y_center"]][df['id']==i].stack().to_frame().T
    df=df.T.drop_duplicates().T
    pd.DataFrame(df).to_csv('%d id.csv'% (i) , index = True, header=True)
```

Comment: The error indicates there is a missing comma between your column names

Comment: so what should i do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure what you want to do.

```py
for i in s:     
    df=df[["id" ,"x_center" , "y_center"]][df['id']==i].stack().to_frame().T
    df=df.T.drop_duplicates().T
    pd.DataFrame(df).to_csv('%d id.csv'% (i) , index = True, header=True)
```

In this for loop, `df` is changed after each loop. So after the first loop, `df` is like

```py
   0                  
  id x_center y_center
0  1        3        5
```

You can see that there is multi-columns, that's why you got `['id' 'x_center' 'y_center'] not in index`.

To fix this, I think the best way is to keep a copy of original dataframe and filter on that dataframe.

```py
origin = pd.read_csv('./1_1.csv')
origin = origin.sort_values(by = 'id')
s = df['id'].unique()

for i in s:
    df = origin.copy()
    df = df[["id" ,"x_center" , "y_center"]][df['id']==i].stack().to_frame().T
    df = df.T.drop_duplicates().T
    pd.DataFrame(df).to_csv('%d id.csv'% (i) , index = True, header=True)
```